# How to remove inspection in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, inspection

I've added the SQL inspection inside `body` tag in HTML file. And now I can't use Emmet. It gives SQL code completion.

How to remove it? I tried to reset to default.

Comment: Look at `Language Injections` -- it will be one of the rules with the "Project" scope. If not sure -- post a screenshot with all rules here.

Comment: Thanks. It workes.